# How to efficiently write a GNU makefile with several modules with an arbitrary number of dependencies in Fortran

Tags: makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

My makefile currently looks like this:

```
#Source file locations
VPATH = :../AHMCodePara

#Compiler
CC = mpifort

#Debugging Flags
#Flags =

#Regular flags
Flags = -Ofast -mkl=sequential

# File name labels
FF =
DE =
Const =
OBJDIR = OBJ

# make object directory
$(OBJDIR):
        -mkdir $(OBJDIR)
CC += -module $(OBJDIR)

#Object File List
Inputs =
Tools = $(OBJDIR)/$(Const)Inputs.o
Diag$(DE) = $(Tools)
PreAnalysis = $(Tools) $(OBJDIR)/Tools.o
DOSsetupPara$(DE) = $(PreAnalysis) $(OBJDIR)/PreAnalysis.o $(OBJDIR)/Diag$(DE).o
$(Const)AHMRGv3 = $(Tools) $(OBJDIR)/Diag$(DE).o $(OBJDIR)/DOSsetupPARA$(DE).o

#Object File List
obj = $(OBJDIR)/$(Const)Inputs.o $(OBJDIR)/Diag$(DE).o $(OBJDIR)/Tools.o \
$(OBJDIR)/PreAnalysis.o $(OBJDIR)/DOSsetupPARA$(DE).o $(OBJDIR)/$(Const)AHMRGv3.o

# dependence files
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.f90 $(%)
#       @$(%)
        @-rm -f #<~
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(Flags)

All: V3.e

# Target
V3.e: $(obj)
        $(CC) $(Flags) -o $@ $^

clean:
        rm $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(OBJDIR)/*.mod
```

It used to be similar to this one:

```
LOC = ../../AHMCode/
CC = gfortran
#Debugging
#Flags = -O0 -g -fcheck=all -Wall -llapack
#Normal
Flags = -O3 -I/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/ -lblas -llapack
FF = _Old
IG = #IGNORE or nothing
TT = #TYPE or nothing
V3$(FF).e: Inputs.o Tools.o PreAnalysis.o DOSsetup$(IG).o Diag$(TT).o AHMRGv3_Manyruns.o
        $(CC) $(Flags) AHMRGv3_Manyruns.o Diag$(TT).o DOSsetup$(IG).o PreAnalysis.o Tools.o Inputs.o -o V3$(FF).e

Inputs.o: Inputs.f90
        $(CC) $(Flags) -c Inputs.f90

Tools.o: $(LOC)Tools.f90 Inputs.o
        $(CC) $(Flags) -c $(LOC)Tools.f90

PreAnalysis.o: $(LOC)PreAnalysis.f90 Inputs.o Tools.o
        $(CC) $(Flags) -c $(LOC)PreAnalysis.f90

DOSsetup$(IG).o: $(LOC)DOSsetup$(IG).f90 Inputs.o Tools.o PreAnalysis.o Diag$(TT).o
        $(CC) $(Flags) -c $(LOC)DOSsetup$(IG).f90

Diag$(TT).o: $(LOC)Diag$(TT).f90 Inputs.o
        $(CC) $(Flags) -c $(LOC)Diag$(TT).f90

AHMRGv3_Manyruns.o: AHMRGv3_ManyRuns.f90 DOSsetup$(IG).o Diag$(TT).o Inputs.o
        $(CC) $(Flags) -c AHMRGv3_Manyruns.f90

clean:
        rm *.o *.mod
```

The section I want to compare in these makefiles is the .o file definitions. In the second makefile, I wrote these all out by hand and it worked great. My intention with the second makefile was to do the same thing but more efficiently.

The problems arose with dependencies. When I initially made changes to my makefile, I didn't put any dependencies at all. This led to problems where I would update Inputs and the relevant files wouldn't recompile (e.g. Tools.o). This is as expected so I've been looking for ways to add dependencies in a creative and efficient way that forces the relevant files to recompile.

As you can see I tried creating variables with the same name as the .f90 and .o to use `$(%)`. This seemed kinda janky (and I didn't really think it would work) but unfortunately didn't solve my problem.

As you can see from the original makefile, the dependencies don't follow any sort of pattern. As well you can see that I am compiling Fortran and I'm pretty sure that -gen-dep doesn't do anything and if it does I'm doing it wrong.

Existing questions on the subject have been very unhelpful since the majority uses C++ and that can be very different here.

**EDIT:** I "fixed" my problem. Its not the most efficient and doesn't automatically generate dependencies but I like it in that its not a lot of repetitive lines.

```
#Object File List
oInpt =
oTool = $(OBJDIR)/$(Const)Inputs.o
oPreA = $(oTool) $(OBJDIR)/Tools.o
oDOSs = $(oPreA) $(OBJDIR)/PreAnalysis.o $(OBJDIR)/Diag$(DE).o
oDiag = $(oTool)
oMain = $(oTool) $(OBJDIR)/Diag$(DE).o $(OBJDIR)/DOSsetupPARA$(DE).o
obj = $(OBJDIR)/$(Const)Inputs.o $(OBJDIR)/Tools.o $(OBJDIR)/PreAnalysis.o $(OBJDIR)/Diag$(DE).o \
$(OBJDIR)/DOSsetupPARA$(DE).o $(OBJDIR)/$(Const)AHMRGv3.o


# dependence files
$(OBJDIR)/$(Const)Inputs.o: $(oInpt)
$(OBJDIR)/Tools.o: $(oTool)
$(OBJDIR)/PreAnalysis.o: $(oPreA)
$(OBJDIR)/Diag$(DE).o: $(oDiag)
$(OBJDIR)/DOSsetupPARA$(DE).o: $(oDOSs)
$(OBJDIR)/$(Const)AHMRGv3.o: $(oMain)
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.f90
        @-rm -f #<~
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(Flags)

All: V3.e
# Target
V3.e: $(obj)
        $(CC) $(Flags) -o $@ $^
```

I just made multiple rules for each target. One a default rule that actually compiles the `.o` files and the other that specifies the dependencies for each `.f90` file.

Comment: Doesn't gfortran support the same set of options for generating dependency lists that GCC does?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read that gfortran accepts the `-M` option(s)...?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. But I am using mpifort to compile. I know its a wrapper and does use gfortran but I've noticed inconsistencies with some support. I eventually resolved my issue but maybe not in the best way. Edited my post.

Comment: You can just use some modern build software that can handle this automatically (scons, waf, cmake, fobis...)